# How to make python's socketIO-client libraries wait(seconds=1) non blocking?

Tags: socket.io

I'm using the socketIO-client 0.6.5 for a python client that communicates with a  node server that uses socketio. My problem is, in order for a client listener to receive data from the server, i have to use the wait() method. wait() hangs the program infinitely while wait(seconds=) hangs the program for the no.of seconds.

I'm using this for a game where the listener will be executed inside the game loop continuously, but if i use the wait() method, the game loop is going to be stuck for the number of seconds which i can't have. The code is way too huge for me to put here but i'm putting a snippet that is representative of the actual code.

```
def main():
    sc = Sock_Con()
    while(True):
        sc.push_player_location(2,3)
        socketIO.on('get_player_location', sc.on_player_location)
        socketIO.wait(seconds=1)
```

if i don't use the wait() method, the data never gets picked from the client. If i do use it the program hangs for the number of seconds. Is there something i'm missing or is there a workaround?